# Solve the recurrence relation $f(n) = 4f(n/3)+5$ where $n=3^k, k=1,2,3...$ and $f(1)=5$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation:

$f(n) = 4f(n/3)+5$ where $n=3^k, k=1,2,3...$ and $f(1)=5$

I never seen a recurrence relation like this before. What would I need to use or do to solve this?

Comment: You could, as usual, try induction.

Comment: If you are only looking for an asymptotic bound, you can use [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Comment: If $n=3^k$ then $n/3=3^{k-1}$ and it becomes a usual recurrence, provided know $f(1)$ and only want it for $f(3^k),$ $k \ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(3^k)=g(k)+c,k=0\implies?$

$5=g(k)-4g(k-1)+c-4c$

Set $c-4c=5$ so that $g(k)=4g(k-1)=4^rg(k-r)=4^kg(0)$

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can find a tight result from the mater theorem and we can say $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_34})$, and as $n = 3^k$, $f(n) \sim (3^k)^{\log_34} = 4^k$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which I find useful is the following:

As already mentioned by Lucas Henrique, you can first of all define $a_k := f(3^k)$. This gives you the relation
$$
a_k = 4a_{k-1} + 5, \quad \quad a_0 = 5
$$
From here on, you have several options. You can use generating functions, just plug in some values and try to find a pattern or assume you have a "big" $k$ and use the above formula several times:
\begin{eqnarray}
a_k &=& 4a_{k-1} +5\\
& = & 4 (4a_{k-2}+5)+5 = 4^2 a_{k-2} + (4+1)\cdot 5\\
& = & 4^2 (4a_{k-3} +5)+(4+1) \cdot5 = 4^3 a_{k-3} + (4^2 + 4 + 1)\cdot 5\\
& = & \dots
\end{eqnarray}
Now you may already derive a formula from that.

*Hint: for $q \neq -1$, one has $\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$*